# SQL - Apply condition to multiple columns with similar names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to know if it's possible to apply a filter to multiple columns with similar names.

Columns:

```
a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3
```

Is it possible to write something like:

`WHERE like "a%" IS NULL`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Short answer: no. You need to repeat the condition for each column.

Comment: Pivot columns into rows, or dynamic sql

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @GMB: it is possible in Postgres ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=26138055f8a1e563e3a35fcadc756426

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I see your point. It is also possible to pivot/search/unpivot - this is why I mentionned this was a *short answer*...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name all columns starting with "a" are null.

Comment: You can probably do something like that with help of FOR XML, but it's probably quicker to type them out :)